# How can I get device name from ip address in Android?

Tags: android

I want to ask, I have a problem I have tried to get an IP address from a hotspot connection and now I still don't understand how we can get the device name from the IP address on Android.

I just tried using this code:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName ("192.168.43.81");
String hostname = address.getCanonicalHostName ();
```

But after I tried using the above code still get ip: 192.168.43.81 I can't get about the device name via hotspot or wifi. Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: Some hosts provide a reverse DNS entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup other than that, there is no way to get a host name from an IP address on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following to get the name of the WiFi network you are connected:

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
String name = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

Answer (score -1):

**To get Device I.P.**

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);String ipAddress = BigInteger.valueOf(wm.getDhcpInfo().netmask).toString();
```

**To get Device Information (Name,Year of Manufacturing etc)**

```
StringBuffer infoBuffer = new StringBuffer();
infoBuffer.append("-------------------------------------\n");
infoBuffer.append("Model :" + Build.MODEL + "\n");//The end-user-visible name for the end product.
infoBuffer.append("Device: " + Build.DEVICE + "\n");//The name of the industrial design.
infoBuffer.append("Manufacturer: " + Build.MANUFACTURER + "\n");//The manufacturer of the product/hardware.
infoBuffer.append("Board: " + Build.BOARD + "\n");//The name of the underlying board, like "goldfish".
infoBuffer.append("Brand: " + Build.BRAND + "\n");//The consumer-visible brand with which the product/hardware will be associated, if any.
infoBuffer.append("Serial: " + Build.SERIAL + "\n");infoBuffer.append("-------------------------------------\n");
```

**Android doc:** This 'Serial' field was deprecated in API level **O**.Use getSerial() instead.A hardware serial number, if available. Alphanumeric only, case-insensitive. For apps targeting SDK higher than `N_MR1` this field is set to UNKNOWN.

I just used AlertDialog to show device informationAlertDialog.Builder dialog = new

```
AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setTitle("Device information:");
dialog.setMessage(infoBuffer);//StringBuffer which we appended the device informations.
dialog.show();
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question but i want after we detect ip address we can detected device name from ip address mean like : ip 192.168.43.81 is samsung device in hotspot i can know ip 192.168.43.81 is samsung device from hosting thanks